# Which 90 year old vampire did Hope kiss in The Originals?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-originals, legacies

In *Legacies* S01E08 "Maybe I Should Start From The End", Hope mentions to Landon that she kissed a 90 year old vampire who tried to kill his mother but I don't remember such events from *The Originals*. So when did this happen and who was this guy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

His name was Roman Sienna. In *The Originals* S05E06, Roman is revealed to have kidnapped Hayley ultimately leading to her death later in the episode. This event takes place around 85 years after Klaus eviscerated his father and village in 1930's Germany making Roman around 90 years old.